# Convert ECEF Velocity to NED Velocity

Tags: navigation, frame, gnss

My GNSS modules gives me one NMEA packet with ECEF velocity. My doubt is about how i convert these 3 vectors to NED frame. Can i use the conventional matrix rotation [MathWorksRef](https://www.mathworks.com/help/aeroblks/directioncosinematrixeceftoned.html). If yes, i use the latitude and longitude with the same timestamp of the velocity points, or other?